# Excel Date Formula with a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have 3 fields in excel as follows:

Cell **A1=2012 A2=12 A3=15** which contains year, month & date value respectively. And I want to make a date string out of it.

I know it's very easy to achieve using Date() function. 
**But I also want the cell to remain blank if any of A1,A2 or A3 is blank.**

Anybody has a formula/logic for this?

Comment: Answer is =IF(COUNT(A1:A3)=3,DATE(A1,A2,A3),"")

Comment: You should post your answer in the answers area.  That way, you can mark your question as answered, and gain some rep.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in Excel 2007 or later would be to use this formula

`=IFERROR((A1&"-"&A2&"-"&A3)+0,"")`

Not only would that show a blank if any of the 3 cells is blank but would also show a blank if you had an invalid date like 2012-2-30. Your version would show that as 1st March

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you wanted your function to return a *string*, be aware that the DATE() function returns a *date*.

To return a *date*:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A2="",A3=""),"",DATE(A1,B1,C1))
```

To return a *string*:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A2="",A3=""),"",TEXT(DATE(A1,B1,C1),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

You may replace "yyyy-MM-dd" with any date display format you like.